# MySQL crash (mysqld got exception 0xc0000005)

Tags: mysql, crash

I use MySQL 8.0.24 on Windows Server 2016 1607 (in an ESX environnment) and have regulary some MySQL crashes (the MySQL service stops) always with the same stored procedure call ; last week, I was using the 8.0.23 version of MySQL and had the same issues but with another stored procedure call (procedures are called by C# through the MySQL .Net Connector 8.0.23).

Important information : I have a database named *cube* (which is a MySQL key word but which was not in the previous MySQL version I used: MySQL 5) and I can't rename it (a lot of other databases use this database, with "*cube.*" references)

I can't explicitaly reproduce the bug (however, it occurs many times a day).

Here after, the error MySQL log content :

```
09:27:05 UTC - mysqld got exception 0xc0000005 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x1e66537b080
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
7ff716848699    mysqld.exe!?walk@Unique@@QEAA_NP6AHPEAXI0@Z0@Z()
7ff716978922    mysqld.exe!?val_str@Item_func_group_concat@@UEAAPEAVString@@PEAV2@@Z()
7ff716656bd9    mysqld.exe!?cache_value@Item_cache_str@@UEAA_NXZ()
7ff716851b92    mysqld.exe!?send_data@Query_result_scalar_subquery@@UEAA_NPEAVTHD@@AEBV?$mem_root_deque@PEAVItem@@@@@Z()
7ff716909a30    mysqld.exe!?ExecuteIteratorQuery@Query_expression@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff71690b0d6    mysqld.exe!?execute@Query_expression@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff71684d91d    mysqld.exe!?exec@SubqueryWithResult@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff71684d88e    mysqld.exe!?exec@Item_subselect@@UEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff716854357    mysqld.exe!?val_str@Item_singlerow_subselect@@UEAAPEAVString@@PEAV2@@Z()
7ff7166e46de    mysqld.exe!?val_str@Item_func_conv_charset@@UEAAPEAVString@@PEAV2@@Z()
7ff7165d4287    mysqld.exe!?val_str@Item_func_case@@UEAAPEAVString@@PEAV2@@Z()
7ff716656bd9    mysqld.exe!?cache_value@Item_cache_str@@UEAA_NXZ()
7ff71665f0cb    mysqld.exe!?has_value@Item_cache@@QEAA_NXZ()
7ff71666c7ae    mysqld.exe!?val_str@Item_cache_str@@UEAAPEAVString@@PEAV2@@Z()
7ff716698727    mysqld.exe!?val_int@Item_func_find_in_set@@UEAA_JXZ()
7ff7165c19ff    mysqld.exe!?compare_int_signed@Arg_comparator@@QEAAHXZ()
7ff7165d3436    mysqld.exe!?val_int@Item_func_ne@@UEAA_JXZ()
7ff71666a0ed    mysqld.exe!?val_bool@Item@@UEAA_NXZ()
7ff7165d217e    mysqld.exe!?val_int@Item_cond_and@@UEAA_JXZ()
7ff716a7170d    mysqld.exe!?Read@FilterIterator@@UEAAHXZ()
7ff716a71031    mysqld.exe!?Read@AggregateIterator@@UEAAHXZ()
7ff7169099e8    mysqld.exe!?ExecuteIteratorQuery@Query_expression@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff71690b0d6    mysqld.exe!?execute@Query_expression@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff71684d91d    mysqld.exe!?exec@SubqueryWithResult@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff71684d88e    mysqld.exe!?exec@Item_subselect@@UEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff716854357    mysqld.exe!?val_str@Item_singlerow_subselect@@UEAAPEAVString@@PEAV2@@Z()
7ff7166666bb    mysqld.exe!?send@Item@@UEAA_NPEAVProtocol@@PEAVString@@@Z()
7ff71662f65a    mysqld.exe!?send_result_set_row@THD@@QEAA_NAEBV?$mem_root_deque@PEAVItem@@@@@Z()
7ff7169fe2a3    mysqld.exe!?send_data@Query_result_send@@UEAA_NPEAVTHD@@AEBV?$mem_root_deque@PEAVItem@@@@@Z()
7ff716909a30    mysqld.exe!?ExecuteIteratorQuery@Query_expression@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff71690b0d6    mysqld.exe!?execute@Query_expression@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff71683c201    mysqld.exe!?execute_inner@Sql_cmd_dml@@MEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff71683c07b    mysqld.exe!?execute@Sql_cmd_dml@@UEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff716789a71    mysqld.exe!?mysql_execute_command@@YAHPEAVTHD@@_N@Z()
7ff7169b1118    mysqld.exe!?exec_core@sp_instr_stmt@@UEAA_NPEAVTHD@@PEAI@Z()
7ff7169b351b    mysqld.exe!?reset_lex_and_exec_core@sp_lex_instr@@AEAA_NPEAVTHD@@PEAI_N@Z()
7ff7169b3c95    mysqld.exe!?validate_lex_and_execute_core@sp_lex_instr@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@PEAI_N@Z()
7ff7169b15b4    mysqld.exe!?execute@sp_instr_stmt@@UEAA_NPEAVTHD@@PEAI@Z()
7ff716747b19    mysqld.exe!?execute@sp_head@@AEAA_NPEAVTHD@@_N@Z()
7ff716748b8b    mysqld.exe!?execute_procedure@sp_head@@QEAA_NPEAVTHD@@PEAV?$mem_root_deque@PEAVItem@@@@@Z()
7ff716a68659    mysqld.exe!?execute_inner@Sql_cmd_call@@MEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff71683c07b    mysqld.exe!?execute@Sql_cmd_dml@@UEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff716789a71    mysqld.exe!?mysql_execute_command@@YAHPEAVTHD@@_N@Z()
7ff716784c2f    mysqld.exe!?dispatch_sql_command@@YAXPEAVTHD@@PEAVParser_state@@@Z()
7ff716783a4c    mysqld.exe!?dispatch_command@@YA_NPEAVTHD@@PEBTCOM_DATA@@W4enum_server_command@@@Z()
7ff71678500e    mysqld.exe!?do_command@@YA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff7165d64a8    mysqld.exe!?modify_thread_cache_size@Per_thread_connection_handler@@SAXK@Z()
7ff7179edbe1    mysqld.exe!?set_compression_level@Zstd_comp@compression@transaction@binary_log@@UEAAXI@Z()
7ff7175d1d1c    mysqld.exe!?my_thread_join@@YAHPEAUmy_thread_handle@@PEAPEAX@Z()
7ff936a4fb80    ucrtbase.dll!_o__realloc_base()
7ff937ca84d4    KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
7ff93a421781    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (1e602cf1038): select ...
```

Thanks by advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried repairing or reinstalling the database server or the operating system? Or to test on another computer?

Comment: I have another computer (UAT) with the same configuration and the problem is the same (same issue on the same stored procedure and before the MySQL upgrade the issue was the same too with the same previous stored procedure). Can you guide me for repairing or reinstalling the database server (its a Production environnment) ?

Answer (score 0):

I happens when a query

- has no data
- with “GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT )”
- without “GROUP BY”
- uses index/primary key (int type) in WHERE clause.

(It returns an empty row if you don't use DISTINCT.)

I think it's a bug.
It's new behavior on mysql 8. It was good on version 5.

Comment: Hello, I will check if my queries match these conditions.